# Select all rows that have at least a list of features with wildcard support

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, tags, entity-relationship

given a table definition:

```
Objects:
 obj_id | obj_name
 -------|--------------
  1     | object1
  2     | object2
  3     | object3

Tags:
  tag_id | tag_name
  -------|--------------
   1     | code:python
   2     | code:cpp
   3     | color:green
   4     | colorful
   5     | image

objects_tags:
  obj_id | tag_id
  -------|---------
   1     | 1
   1     | 2
   2     | 1
   2     | 3
   3     | 1
   3     | 2
   3     | 3
```

I'd like to select objects that contain all tags from given list **with wildcards**. Similar question has been asked several times and answer to simpler variant looks more or less like this:

```
SELECT obj_id,count(*) c FROM objects_tags
INNER JOIN objects USING(obj_id)    
INNER JOIN tags USING(tag_id)
WHERE (name GLOB 'code*' OR name GLOB 'color*')
GROUP BY obj_id
HAVING (c==2)
```

However this solution doesn't work with wildcards. Is it possible to create similar query that would return objects that for each given wildcard query returned at least 1 tag? Checking if `c>=2` doesn't work because one wildcard tag can return multiple results while another may return 0 still passing query even though it shouldn't.

I considered builting dynamic query built by client software that would consist of N `INTERSECT`s (one per tag) because there's probably not going to be many of them but it sounds like really dirty solution and if there's any more SQL way then I'd prefer to use it.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite supports [WITH clause](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) so I would try to use it to determine all tags first, and then use these tags to find objects in the below way.
The example ([demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/1e0ca/7)) is made for PostGreSQL because I could not run SQLIte on any online tester, but I belive you will convert it easily to SQLite:

---

this query retrieves all tags:

```
WITH tagss AS (
  SELECT * FROM Tags
  WHERE tag_name LIKE 'code:%' OR tag_name LIKE 'color:%'
)
SELECT * FROM tagss;

| tag_id |    tag_name |
|--------|-------------|
|      1 | code:python |
|      2 |    code:cpp |
|      3 | color:green |
```

and the final query uses the above subquery in this way:

```
WITH tagss AS (
  SELECT * FROM Tags
  WHERE tag_name LIKE 'code:%' OR tag_name LIKE 'color:%'
)
SELECT obj_id,count(*) c 
FROM objects_tags
INNER JOIN tagss USING(tag_id)
WHERE tag_name IN ( SELECT tag_name FROM tagss) 
GROUP BY obj_id
HAVING count(*) >= (
    SELECT count(*) FROM tagss
)

| obj_id | c |
|--------|---|
|      3 | 3 |
```

Comment: it's almost perfect, except it requires all tags to be present so if there's `code:%` tag, object in order to be selected has to have all code tags. Not at least one.